# changing 'invisible' chaaracters to letters, game of hangman

Tags: java, methods, character, hidden

so in my program im trying to incorporate a couple of different classse into my main program which i am coming up with the code.

What i am given

```
    Dictionary() {
        dictionary = new String[NUMBER_OF_WORDS];
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner(new File(FILE_NAME));
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Dictionary class cannot find file \"dictionaryData.txt\".");
            System.out.println("Please make sure that the file is in the project folder.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_WORDS; i++) {
            dictionary[i] = inputStream.next();
        }
    }

    public String getRandomWord(){
        Random generator = new Random();
        String temp = new String();
        temp += dictionary[generator.nextInt(NUMBER_OF_WORDS)];
        return temp;
    }

    public boolean find(String word) {
        int count = 0;
        int lowerIndex = 0;
        int upperIndex = NUMBER_OF_WORDS - 1;
        int middleIndex;
        while(lowerIndex <= upperIndex){
            middleIndex = (lowerIndex + upperIndex) / 2;
            count++;
            if(word.equalsIgnoreCase(dictionary[middleIndex])) { // found it
                return true;
            }
            else if (word.compareToIgnoreCase(dictionary[middleIndex]) < 0) { // word smaller than middle
                upperIndex = middleIndex - 1;
            }
            else { // word is larger than middle
                lowerIndex = middleIndex + 1;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

along with another class WordHider

```
     WordHider() {
        secretWord = new String();
        wordMask = new String();
    }

    public String getWordMask() {
        return wordMask;
    }

    public String getSecretWord() {
        return secretWord;
    }

    public void setSecretWord(String newSecretWord) {
        secretWord = newSecretWord.toLowerCase();
        if (secretWord.length() > 0) {
            wordMask = HIDE_CHAR;
            for (int i = 1; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {
                wordMask += HIDE_CHAR;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isHiddenWordFound() {
        for (int i = 0; i < wordMask.length(); i++) {
            if(wordMask.charAt(i) == HIDE_CHAR.charAt(0)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    public int revealLetter(String letter) {
        int count = 0;
        String newFoundWord = "";
        if (letter.length() == 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {
                if ((secretWord.charAt(i) == letter.charAt(0))
                        && (wordMask.charAt(i) == HIDE_CHAR.charAt(0))) {
                    count++;
                    newFoundWord += letter;
                }
                else {
                    newFoundWord += wordMask.charAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
        wordMask = newFoundWord;
        return count;
    }
}
```

and using those classes i have to come up with code that looks like this:

```
Word: **********   Guesses Left: 5
Enter your guess: a
Miss!
Word: **********   Guesses Left: 4
Enter your guess: e
Miss!
Word: **********   Guesses Left: 3
Enter your guess: i
Word: i**i*i****   Guesses Left: 3
Enter your guess: o
Word: i**i*i*o**   Guesses Left: 3
```

And ive got a couple of questions about this,

> 1) i have a dictionaryData.text that i was given and have to implement
>   that into my code. it contains a list of 81thousand words and im not
>   sure how to have my program recognize its there. Dictionary class
>   cannot find file "dictionaryData.txt". Please make sure that the file
>   is in the project folder. ^ i get that error when i try and print a
>   random word
>
> 2) How do i get my program to change the letters of a word to
>   stars(Hide the word)
>
> 3) put it all in a loop?

Comment: What is `FILE_NAME`? Where is your `dictionaryData.txt` file located? Also ask one question at a time.

Comment: dictionaryData.txt is a whole seperate file i have

Comment: I am asking in regards to first question as you said `im not sure how to have my program recognize its there`

Comment: ok so ive got my main program Program3, then 2 other classes, Dictionary and WordHider. In order for Dictionary to work it needs to recognize and find my text file dictionaryData.txt

Comment: I understand that part. What i am asking is waht is String you are passing to `FILE_NAME` and If that file name is correct and located at the place your FILE_NAME says then it will read the file other wise it will throw FileNotFoundEcxception.

Answer (score 0):

Parts of the Dictionary class and the WordHider class are missing.  Nevertheless, I'll try and answer your questions.

1) Like I said, you're missing part of the Dictionary class.  You incorporate the class like this:

```
Dictionary dictionary = new Dictionary();
String word = dictionary.getRandomWord();
```

2) Like this:

```
wordHider.setSecretWord(word);
```

3) I'm not sure what "it" is, but yes, your user has to guess a letter.  Then you have to check to see if the letter is in the word.  Like this:

```
wordHider.revealLetter(letter);
```

Then you have to display the word and let the user guess another letter.  This guess / check / display has to be in a loop.